# What is the best method to compute the eigenvalues of a large non-symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-precision

I have a square matrix with the dimension of $1600\times1600$. I need to compute the eigenvalues of this matrix and investigate its observability.

The usual way is to compute the eigenvalues of this matrix in MATLAB and proceed. But I know that the computation of eigenvalues is sensitive to numeric precision specially for large matrices.

My question is: What is the best (numerically most stable) method to computate the eigenvalues of a large non-symmetric matrix?

Thanks in advance,
Reza

Comment: what is your criterion for saying "this is a good estimation of the eigenvalues" ? so I'd say it depends on your matrix and what you want to do

Comment: I would tell the method in which the effect of numeric precision is minimal.

Comment: you don't want to explain where your matrix comes from and what you want to do with the eigenvalues ?

Comment: The matix has come from the linearization of a chemical process and I want to investigate its local observability.
I want to know what are the available methods to compute the eigenvalues of such large matrices numerically and which is more robust against the numeric precision...